# Why Jquery outer for loop complete its all iteration first in nested forloop

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to use nested jquery ajax to add rows in datatable but my outer for loop complete its all iteration first and add all the rows belonging to outer loop in datatable then it goes to inner for loop and execute inner ajax call...
please help me to solve this problem

Bellow is my code.

````
{
    $.ajax({
        url: getProjDocAddress,
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: {
            project_id: project_id,
            _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) 
        {

            if(result['project_docs_section'] != null)
            {
                var len = result['project_docs_section'].length;
                var table = projectDocsDataTable.DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "searching": true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "sDom": 'lfrtip'
                });
                var index=1;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                {
                    var id = result['project_docs_section'][i].id;
                    var section_title = result['project_docs_section'][i].section_title;
                    var project_id = result['project_docs_section'][i].project_id;
                    table.row.add( [
                            section_title+"<a class='manage-drawing-files-btn' data-value='"+id+"' data-id='0' data-path='' data-url='' data-type='docs' data-file-type='' data-is-docs='0' data-is-add='1'> <i class='fa fa-upload'></i></a>",
                            '',
                            '',
                            ''
                        ] ).draw(false),
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url + "/" + id,
                        type: "POST",
                        async: true,
                        data: {
                            project_id: project_id,
                            _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) 
                        {
                            if(response['projectFiles'] != null)
                            {
                                var len1 = response['projectFiles'].length;
                                for(var j=0; j<len1; j++)
                                {
                                    table.row.add( [
                                        index,
                                        response['projectFiles'][j].type,
                                        response['projectFiles'][j].file_type,
                                        '<center><a href="'+response['projectFiles'][j].file_url+'" download="'+response['projectFiles'][j].type+'"><i data-id="'+response['projectFiles'][j].id+'"class="edit-doc-btn fa fa-download text-primary icon-action"></i></a><a  data-tkn="'+response['projectFiles'][j].token+'" data-id="'+response['projectFiles'][j].id+'" data-path="'+response['projectFiles'][j].file + response['projectFiles'][j].file_name +'" data-url="'+response['projectFiles'][j].file_url+'"data-desc="'+response['projectFiles'][j].description+'"    data-type="'+response['projectFiles'][j].type+'" data-is-docs="1" data-file-type="'+response['projectFiles'][j].file_type+'"  " class=" manage-drawing-files-btn edit-doc-btn feather icon-edit-2 text-info icon-action"></i></a><a data-id="'+response['projectFiles'][j].id+'" class="delete-doc-btn feather icon-trash-2 text-danger icon-action"></i></a></center>'
                                    ] ).draw(false);
                                    index++;
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}```
````

Comment: Did you try setting the `async: false` in your ajax config? The outer loop won't wait for an ajax response if it's async, therefore the outer loop will finish before your ajax requests are done

Comment: yes i tried but i get the same result.